# Rearranging a string of numbers from highest to lowest C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

What I'm trying to do is to create a function that will rearrange a string of numbers like "1234" to "4321". I'm certain that there are many much more efficient ways to do this than my method but I just want to see what went wrong with what I did because I'm a beginner at programming and can use the knowledge to get better.
My thought process for the code was to:

- find the largest number in the inputted string
- add the largest number into a list
- remove the largest number from the inputted string
- find the largest number again from the (now shorter) string

So I made a function that found the largest number in a string and it worked fine:

```
static int LargestNumber(string num)
    {
        int largestnumber = 0;
        char[] numbers = num.ToCharArray();
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            int prevNumber = (int) char.GetNumericValue(number);
            if (prevNumber >= largestnumber)
            {
                largestnumber = prevNumber;
            }

        }
        return largestnumber;
    }
```

Now the **rearranging function** is what I am having problems with:

```
static List<int> Rearrange(string num)
    {
        List<int> rearranged = new List<int>(); // to store rearranged numbers
        foreach (var number in num) //for every number in the number string
        {
            string prevnumber = number.ToString(); // the previous number in the loop
            if (prevnumber == LargestNumber(num).ToString()) // if the previous number is the larges number in the inputted string (num)
            {
                rearranged.Add(Convert.ToInt32(prevnumber)); // put the previous number into the list

                // removing the previous number (largest) from the inputted string and update the inputted string (which should be now smaller)
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(num);
                sb.Remove(num.IndexOf(number), 1); 
                num = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        return rearranged; // return the final rearranged list of numbers
    }
```

When I run this code (fixed for concatenation):

```
var rearranged = Rearrange("3250");
string concat = String.Join(" ", rearranged.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(concat);
```

All I get is:

```
5
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong -  the code doesn't seem to be going back after removing '5' which i s the highest number then removing the next highest number/

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [Kaprekar's Routine](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/56tbds/20161010_challenge_287_easy_kaprekars_routine/)? If so, you can check [the way I did it](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/56tbds/20161010_challenge_287_easy_kaprekars_routine/d8nedm0) :)

Comment: `var ordered = New String(nums.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(q => Convert.ToInt32(q)).ToArray())`

Comment: @Plutonix surely the OP isn't asking for an in framework solution, but rather what is wrong with their attempt at the algorithm.

Comment: yup, thats why it is a comment.  as a self described "beginner at programming" they might not know there are Other Ways

Comment: Pretty sure they want you to ask a new question, not modify this one. Your original question of "why isn't this list printing" has been answered. As for your new question, I feel like `num = sb.ToString();` is not doing what you think. I actually don't fully understand it at the moment because you cannot modify a variable you are iterating over, so because strings are immutable I'm pretty sure the `foreach` is iterating the original string. Because of this, you are not removing any values from the `foreach`'s copy of `num` and is why it only prints the largest number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your `if` statement within your loop.

```
if (prevnumber == LargestNumber(num).ToString()
{
    rearranged.Add(Convert.ToInt32(prevnumber));
    //...
}
```

You only ever add to your List `rearranged` if the value of `prevnumber` is the largest value, which is false for every number but `5`, so the only value that ever gets added to the list is `5`.

That's the answer to why it's only returning `5`, but I don't think that will make your method work properly necessarily. You're doing a very dangerous thing by changing the value of the collection you are iterating over (the characters in `num`) from within the loop itself. Other answers have been written for you containing a method that rearranges the numbers as you've described.

Comment: So it isn't possible to update the collection while looping over it?

Comment: @user3124306 It's possible, and you are doing it, but it's ill-advised (and I think it actually throws an exception when iterating over an IEnumerable). When you modify the collection that you're iterating over during an iteration, you potentially change the behaviour of subsequent iterations. This is only a general recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Your Rearrange method is returning `List<int>` when you try to write that to the console, the best it can do is write `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]` (its type)

Instead of trying to write the list, convert it first into a data type that can be written (string for example)

eg:

```
var myList = Rearrange("3250");
string concat = String.Join(" ", myList.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(concat);
```

Comment: Doh! Yeah, I forgot about that. My code doesn't work, though, just outputs 5  :/ I don't think I implemented my method/algorithm correctly

Answer (score 1):

Building on pats comment you could iterate through your list and write them to the console.

e.g.

```
foreach(var i in  Rearrange(3250))
{
    console.writeline(i.ToString());
}
```

or if you want to see the linq example.

```
using system.linq;
Rearrange(3250).foreach(i => console.writeline(i.ToString()));
```

--edit after seeing you're only getting '5' output
This is because your function only adds number to the list if they are the largest number in your list, which is why 5 is only being added and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading your first sentence
Does not test for integers

```
    static int ReversedNumber(string num)
    {
        char[] numbers = num.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        Array.Reverse(numbers);
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Concat(numbers));
        return (int.Parse(String.Concat(numbers)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Rearrange` method can be written easily using [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) *(or similar with (`List<T>`)* :

```
int[] Rearrange(int num)
{
    var arr = num.ToString ().ToCharArray ();
    Array.Sort (arr, (d1, d2) => d2 - d1);
    return Array.ConvertAll (arr, ch => ch - '0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your foreach loop within Rearrange method only loop through the original num. The algorithm doesn't continue to go through the new num string after you have removed the largest number.
You can find the problem by debugging, this foreach loop in Rearrange goes only 4 times if your input string is "3250".